# How to enable discrete graphic on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, graphics, amd-graphics

I have AMD Radeon R7 M440 graphic card and i want to enable it.
So, there is annoying screen blinking and I don't know why.
Current graphic card is Intel Kabylake GT2.
I tried with official AMDGPU but it seems like it is not working.
Everything I get is frozen screen when I restart my PC and turn on again.

Comment: Just FYI, AMD graphics drivers are currently a mess on Ubuntu.